# How can I programmatically create a link/URL with querystrings set from parameters?

Tags: 8, uri

In Drupal 8 I customize the filter in the block in the sidebar menu. When the user clicks on the option in the block, I need to pass his choice to the URL.

```
$this->args = \Drupal::request()->query->all();
$args[$id] = $value;
$url = $this->url = Url::fromRoute('<current>');
$url->setOptions(array('query' => $args));
$link = '<a href="' . $url->toString() . '">' . $label . '</a>';
```

And in the end, my URL looks like

```
 drupal/page_view?content_type=type
```

but I need my URL to look like

```
drupal/page_view?content_type%5Btype%5D=type
```

Do you know how can I modify my code?

Answer (score 5):

Let's say if your `$args` is an array like below:

```
$args['content_type'] = 'type';
```

Then you have to append `type` to it rather than just giving your `$id to $args`

```
$args['content_type'] = ['type' => '123'];
```

Then your overall query will be like:

```
$this->args = \Drupal::request()->query->all();
$this->args = [$id => $value];
$url = $this->url = Url::fromRoute('<current>');
$url->setOptions(array('query' => $args));
$link = '<a href="' . $url->toString() . '">' . $label . '</a>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You try code :

```
$options = ['absolute' => TRUE];
$url = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 526,'destination'=>'router_back'], $options);
$link = Link::fromTextAndUrl('Here is the link', $url)->toString();
```

Result link:`node/526?destination=router_back`

You see more [Url::fromRoute](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromRoute/8.2.x)