# CSRF token is not varying in Ajax callback while submitting form

Tags: forms, ajax, csrf

I have a form with ajax callback as following , on each submit token is not varying , it remains constant for all submit .

wall.routing.yml

```
wall.commentform:
  path: '/commentform'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Comment form'
    _form: '\Drupal\wall\Form\WallCommentPost'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
    _csrf_token: 'TRUE'
```

In from as following

WallCommentPost.php

```
$ajax = [
  'callback' => [$this, '_wall_comment_ajax_form_post'],
  'wrapper' => 'field-type-replace-comment',
  'event' => 'click',
  'progress' => array(
    'type' => 'throbber',
    'message' => '',
  )
];

$form['wall_submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Submit',
  '#ajax' => $ajax,
  '#prefix' => '<div class="col-12 p-1 d-flex justify-content-between"><div class="file_name_insert file_name_insert_data-' . $nid . ' pl-4 text-truncate"></div>',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array(
      'btn',
      $ajax_class,
      'd-none',
      'subbtn-' . $nid
    ),
    'disabled' => 'disabled'
  ),
];
$url = Url::fromRoute('wall.commentform');
$token = \Drupal::csrfToken()->get($url->getInternalPath());

$form['#action'] = Url::fromRoute('wall.commentform')->setOption('query', [FormBuilderInterface::AJAX_FORM_REQUEST => 1, 'token1' => $token])->toString();
```

Comment: I see $token is commented out, is it intentional ? or you missed it ?

Comment: By default that URL itself generating token , I just tested this way by forcefully adding token ,still it remains as a constant value .

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to do. I can see how you're trying to do it, but I don't understand what your goal is, or what is working contrary to what is expected. Not  enough information.

Comment: May be it helps  https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/268262/ ?

Comment: CSRF token should vary on each submit request , that is my goal , as of now the CSRF token passing in the URL  remains constant . how to vary the token value on each submit request ?

Answer (score 0):

After further digging found out the cause for CSRF token not varying.

CSRF token is dependent on session. So until the session is same CSRF token stays same.

Logout and login again and submit the form, you will get new token.

There is an [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2245003) reported in Drupal.org for the same even though it is fixed for Drupal 8, it is not working as expected.